# Using the Jersey client to do a POST operation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

In a Java method, I'd like to use a Jersey client object to do a POST operation on a RESTful web service (also written using Jersey) but am not sure how to use the client to send the values that will be used as FormParam's on the server.  I'm able to send query params just fine.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Not done this yet myself, but a quick bit of Google-Fu reveals a [tech tip on blogs.oracle.com](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with) with examples of exactly what you ask for.

Example taken from the blog post:

```
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("name1", "val1");
formData.add("name2", "val2");
ClientResponse response = webResource
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
    .post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

That any help?

Answer (score 53):

Starting from Jersey 2.x, the `MultivaluedMapImpl` class is replaced by [`MultivaluedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html). You can use it to add form data and send it to the server:

```
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://www.example.com/some/resource");
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
    formData.add("key1", "value1");
    formData.add("key2", "value2");
    Response response = webTarget.request().post(Entity.form(formData));
```

Note that the form entity is sent in the format of `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Comment: Do I still need to `URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8")` the value or will `form()` take care of the correct encoding internally?

Answer (score 18):

It is now the first example in the [Jersey Client documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#client.ex.formpost)

**Example 5.1. POST request with form parameters**

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998").path("resource");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("x", "foo");
form.param("y", "bar");

MyJAXBBean bean =
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
        MyJAXBBean.class);
```

Comment: Does Jersey client automatically convert the return type into `MyJAXBBean.class` ? How to achieve this?

Comment: The last parameter of the call chain is a class telling Jersey to map the response content to a MyJAXBBean object. You can also map it to a string and deserialize it with a tool of your own chosing.

Comment: This is the link if someone's still looking - https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#client.ex.formpost

Answer (score 6):

If you need to do a file upload, you'll need to use MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE.
Looks like MultivaluedMap cannot be used with that so here's a solution with FormDataMultiPart.

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileNameToUpload);

FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart();
part.field("String_key", "String_value");
part.field("fileToUpload", stream, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
String response = WebResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, part);
```

Comment: If you're not posting a text file, you probably want to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE` for the stream...

Answer (score 3):

Simplest:

```
Form form = new Form();
form.add("id", "1");    
form.add("name", "supercobra");
ClientResponse response = webResource
  .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
  .post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this:

```
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("name1", "val1");
formData.add("name2", "val2");
webResource.path("yourJerseysPathPost").queryParams(formData).post();
```