# Using the jersey client to do a POST operation with request params and a request body

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm trying to figure how how to use the Jersey client to send both the request params and the request body of a POST operation.

Currently I know how to do it both of those way individually, but not together.

From here: [Using the Jersey client to do a POST operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136119/using-the-jersey-client-to-do-a-post-operation)

I've gotten this for the request parms:

```
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("name1", "val1");
formData.add("name2", "val2");
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

And for the request body I can do the following:

```
String jsonObject ="... valid json object";
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(String.class, jsonObject);
```

How do I post both a request param with a request body?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured it out..

```
webResource.queryParam("key", "value").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(String.class, jsonObject);
```

Comment: rats, just as I was about to post that: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#queryParams(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap)