# How to send Form Data when using Jersey's WebResource for a POST?

Tags: java, post, jersey, jersey-client

I have a Postman POST request which looks like the following:

[image]

The code I'm using to map the above into code using Jersey's `WebResource` is the following, but it's not working:

```
Client authKeyClient = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = authKeyClient.resource("https://ims-na1-stg1.company.com/token/v1");
String input = "{\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"client_id\":\"orders\",\"client_secret\":\"0af3b233-f1ca-41da-a0fa-61c08d15cadc\",\"code\":\"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dSI6Imltc19uYTEtc\"}";
currentEnv.getImsSecret()).header("code", currentEnv.imsCode).get(String.class);
String response = webResource.post(String.class, input);
```

I end up getting a `400 Bad Request`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Content-Type`. I would also suggest to send request in more structured way to avoid mistype mistakes:

```
MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("name1", "val1");
formData.add("name2", "val2");
ClientResponse response = webResource
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
    .post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

Similar discussion: [Using the Jersey client to do a POST operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136119/using-the-jersey-client-to-do-a-post-operation)