# Rest Service and Client in Java

Tags: java, rest, client

I devoloped the following Rest service:

```
@POST
@Path("getTokenUser")
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getTokenUser(@QueryParam("User")String 
User,@QueryParam("Password")String Password) throws Exception
{
    pToken ptoken=new pToken();
    return ptoken.getAuth_Token(User, Password).toString();    
}
```

And the client:

```
try
  {
    Client cliente=Client.create();
    WebResource wresource=cliente.resource("http://Localhost:8084/API_FE/webresources/Facturacion/getTokenUser");
    String values="{\"User\":\"AbrahamV\",\"Password\":\"1234sa\"}";
    ClientResponse response = wresource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, values);
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);System.out.println(output);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
  }
```

But when I run the client,the rest service doesn't recive anything. I don't know what Im doing bad, I'm new in this.

```
Response Web Service Rest:
run:
{"Message":"Son necesarias las credenciales de acceso","Token":"","Code":"afe-e01"}
```

Comment: Can you add to your question description any kind of log? Maybe you request is reaching the service but not returning any value for a different reason.

Comment: try accessing your rest service url in your browser, and see whats it response

Comment: The path in the service and the path in the client don't appear to match.  Is there something else defining a base path?  What is the response?  Did you debug?

Comment: Also, the client is POSTing JSON but the service expects named parameters.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136119/using-the-jersey-client-to-do-a-post-operation) answer.

Comment: I tried with    MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("name1", "val1");
formData.add("name2", "val2"); to, but it's the same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it.

```
try
  {
    Client cliente=Client.create();
    WebResource wresource=cliente.resource("http://Localhost:8084/API_FE/webresources/Facturacion/getTokenUser");
    MultivaluedMap<String,String> data=new  MultivaluedHashMap();
    data.add("User","Abraham01");
    data.add("Password","14235afe");
    ClientResponse response =wresource.queryParams(data).post(ClientResponse.class);
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);System.out.println(output);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      System.out.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Instead sending a json structure, I send a MultivaluedMap in a queryParams.