# HttpServletRequest JSON parameter found null value in Servlet

Tags: java, json, rest, servlets

I'm using Servlet to handle request and response.

I have used following code to Servlet my request to sublet using webservice:

```
 JSONObject parans = new JSONObject();
    parans.put("commandid", "Enamu7l");
    System.out.println("parans = " + parans);        
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource("URL");
    ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class, parans.toJSONString());
```

Here is my servlet code to receive data.

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String commandid= request.getParameter("commandid");        
    System.out.println(commandid);       
}
```

commandid recieve `null` from webservice.

What to do in webservice to get data in servlet?

Comment: This is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebResource  not sending the data as part of the url, so you can *not* use `request.getParameter`. The data is send as request body using the post method.Read the data using the reader.

```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
       JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        System.out.println(jSONObject.getString("commandid"));
```

Comment: thanks for answer can you tell me sending the data as part of the url from WebResource

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136119/using-the-jersey-client-to-do-a-post-operation

Answer (score 0):

You are sending JSON in **request body**, so you need to get it:

```
String json = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Convert to JSON:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

And get the value:

```
String value = jsonObject.getString("commandid");
```